# jquery 360 slider skin change

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, slider

I am searching for a JS plugin that will generate 360 slider and allow to upload custom skin for it. Something simliar to [this](http://www.360slider.com/)

I've found that this plugin is generating the pseudo 3d slides from lots of image frames (png).

Use Case:

1. User enters the product site with standard skin 360 slider preview.
2. He uploads his own custom skin and browser displays the product 360 slider live preview with new skin.

My question:
Is it possible to do with pure JS ? Or it can be done only in Canvas or with help of other plugin ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is to help people with their programing and does not include recommending any plugins. The answer to your questions (Q1 pure JS?) yes JS does everything. (Q2 only Canvas?) you can use any DOM object that can display an image. You use JS to manipulate the DOM to do what you want e.g. display images one after another as part of a 360 slider, and No you don't need any plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :), how it can be done in pure JS if the animation is a set of frames. How I can change a custom skin pattern of the image ? The user should upload his own pattern and the model should be covered with this pattern after upload.

Comment: That would  need a 3D model of the object being rotated. You would have to create one using a 3D editing package like 3DSMax or Blender. You then not need the images but render the object in realtime using Canvas and webGL context.

Comment: So if i combine Canvas with webGL and the skin uploading form for the user I can make the live skin changing 3d model application, is that right :) ?